# MongoDB utilizing an aggregate average result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents that looks like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
gradeLevels: {type: String},
subject: {type: String},
standard: {type: String},
description: {type: String},
price: {type: String},
numberOfInternalReviews: {type: Number},
reviews: [{
    content: {type: String},
    rating: {type: Number},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    userFirstName: {type: String},
    softDelete: {type : Boolean}
}],
averageUserRating: {type: Number}
});
```

I have them created an aggregate formula that produces the average of the ratings for each review, as such:

```
db.applications.aggregate([
      { $unwind: "$reviews" }, 
      { $group: { _id: "$_id", reviews: { $push: "$reviews" },                                       
                 averageUserRating: { $avg: "$reviews.rating" } } }, 
      { $project: { _id: 0, _id: "$_id", reviews: 1, averageUserRating: 1 } }]);
```

This does produce the correct results of the average, as needed, within the console.

What I need to happen is to push the result into the original object's averageUserRating field.

When I then look at the application document, the averageUserRating is still returning null.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: What are you using in the back-end?

Comment: I am using node.js, express, and mongoose on the back end

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is a type inb project, so: change this:

```
{ $project: { _id: 0, _id: "$_id", reviews: 1, averageUserRating: 1 } }]);
```

to:

```
{ $project: { _id: "$_id", reviews: 1, averageUserRating: 1 } }]);
```

Comment: Thank you, however, the formula itself isn't the issue, I don't think. The formula is correctly producing the average of the review ratings. However, i'm unsure how to use this formula within express or mongoose to grab and save the result within the application object.